# why does next.js return error when calling a method of array that is not assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I get an error when calling an unassigned array literal

```
[1,2,3].forEach(i=>i)
```

In plain JavaScript, this works fine, but in next.js  I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '3')
```

When I assign the array to a variable it works but I don't understand I it does not work without assigning the array

Comment: What do you mean by _"calling an unassigned array literal"_? The code you provide does not throw any error in Next.js for me. Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` does not have a return value, which means in this code

```js
const x = [1, 2, 3].forEach(i => i)
```

`x` is `undefined`.

In this code

```js
let x = [1, 2, 3];
x.forEach(i => i);
```

`x` has the value `[1, 2, 3]` because this is the value that was assigned to `x` in the first line and the second line does not do anything.

Replace `i => i` with `i => 2 * i` and it becomes more clear:

```js
let x = [1, 2, 3];
x.forEach(i => 2 * i);
```

`x` will have the value `[1, 2, 3]` - not `[2, 4, 6]` as you might expect.

Maybe you are looking for `map`:

```js
let x = [1, 2, 3];
let x2 = x.map(i => 2 * i);
// x2 === [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: I mean array methods do not work for unassigned array literals in next.js but work in plain javascript. My question is why I should have to assign an array in next.js but do not in vanilla js

Comment: can you give a specific example of code the works outside of a next.js application, but not in next.js? I tried to reproduce it but I don't get any error, see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-forked-eqbb5t?file=/index.js ; The error message in your question indicates that you seem to do more than just putting the unassigned expression [1,2,3.forEach(...)] in your next.js code - it looks like you are trying to access the properties of it's value, so please share the full code